# adf.test doesn't recognize time series object as time series

Tags: r, time-series

I am testing for the stationarity of a dataset containing monthly inflation rates from January 2018 to May 2023. There are only 2 columns in the .csv file (1st column: date, 2nd column: inflation rate). I have already converted the file into a time series object as seen below but when I run the adf.test it displays this error: "x is not a vector or univariate time series".

```
inf <- read.csv("inf_ph.csv")
inf_ph <- ts(inf,frequency=12,start=c(2018,1))
autoplot(inf_ph[,2],
    main = "Monthly Headline Inflation",
    xlab = "Year",
    ylab = "In Percent (%)")
12*(65/100)^(1/4)
adf.test(inf_ph, nlag=10)
#H0: not stationary
#H1: stationary
```

Comment: Can you please share some data using `dput()`? We can't run your code as we can't access the data. From what you've told us - `inf_ph` has multiple time series. The `adf.test` expects a vector (or univariate time series) but you are passing it two variables: date and inflation rate. Try subsetting `inf` before creating a ts object or passing in `inf_ph[,2]` to `adf.test`.

Comment: Passing in `inf_ph[,2]` worked but now it shows this error: "Error in adf.test(inf_ph[, 2], nlag = 10) : unused argument (nlag = 10)". I used nlag=10 based on this formula 12*(65/100)^(1/4) as suggested by Schwert (1989).

Comment: Which package are you getting the `adf.test` function from? For example, `adf.test` from {tseries} doesn't have an `nlag` argument - that's likely where the error comes from. The version of `adf.test` from {aTSA} does have this argument - make sure you're using the function from the package you think you are. Try using `aTSA::adf.test(inf_ph[, 2], nlag = 10)` instead? Or use `k` instead of `nlag` if using the {tseries} version.

Comment: I ran both the {tseries} and {aTSA} initially which i think caused the problem. `aTSA::adf.test(inf_ph[, 2], nlag = 10)` did the trick though. Thank you so much!